# How to insert widgets into a post?

Tags: widgets

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I would like to add a feature like that of page origin page builder.

I would have just used their plugin but I don't really like the way it's setup. My main question is a guideline on how to make a page builder to have a button with an ability to insert widgets into areas.

I've searched and searched but I've not found any post related to inserting widgets on pages.

I'm not that good with JavaScript but I also have a little knowledge on PHP.

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to be exceptional at JS to pull this off. Start by improving your scripting knowledge and expertise. However, consider in the short run, perhaps using [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), in combination with [`the_widget();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)

Answer (score 1):

You can insert widgets into a post by Shortcode. Just make a shortcode with `dynamic_sidebar()` function to insert your specified sidebar widgets.

```
<?php
add_shortcode('sidebar_widgets', function($atts, $content) {
ob_start();
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'sidebar_id' => '',
),$atts);
?>
    <div>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar($atts['sidebar_id']); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
return $html;
});
```

You can implement this shortcode with any page builder plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Building a page builder would be a much more complex undertaking than some other options. I would suggest creating a child theme from your current one, then creating a custom template (i.e. "tpl-custom-sidebar.php") that has a widgetized sidebar. Then, you would manage the widgets for that template in Appearance > Widgets or the Customizer.

You could create as many or as few of these custom templates as you want, then just select the appropriate template from the dropdown menu in the editor screen.

Another option, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, may be to convert your widgets into shortcodes. By doing this you can paste your shortcodes directly into the editor of the particular post(s) you want to affect. This might be a little easier to keep track of because you can see right in the post content what shortcodes are in use.